# Batch insert into multiple table with sequence

Tags: java, oracle11g, batch-insert

We are facing a problem while implementing a batch insert code in our java application. Below is our table structure -

- We have three tables : Table1, Table2 & Table3.
- Primary key of Table1 (SeqId, which is essentially sequence) is foregn key for rest two tables (Table2 & Table3).

[image: Table Structure]

**Current Implementation :**

As part of current batch operation, for each iteration we are inserting sequentially in Table1 first followed by Table2 & Table3.

[Pseudo Code]

```
INSERT INTO Table1(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Some Val');
INSERT INTO Table2(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (someId2, ID_SEQ.currval, 'Some Val');
INSERT INTO Table3(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (someId3, ID_SEQ.currval, 'Some Val');
```

**What we are trying :**

Now we are trying to implement batch insert. We have created three seperate PreparedStatement and for each iteration we are doing `statement.addBatch();` and at the very end we are executing `statement.executeBatch()` sequentially.

Now the problem is `ID_SEQ.currval` will always take the current sequence value which is not what we want. Agaist each value of SeqId in Table1, we want correponding row in Table2 and Table3.

Is it possible to implement this using batch insert (not a procedure or anonymous block)?

We are using Oracle `11g` and `Java8`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a variable to store the sequence value

```
DECLARE
   ID_SEQ PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   ID_SEQ  := ID_SEQ.nextval;
   INSERT INTO Table1(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (ID_SEQ  , 'Some Val');
   INSERT INTO Table2(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (someId2, ID_SEQ  , 'Some Val');
   INSERT INTO Table3(SeqId, OtherField1) VALUES (someId3, ID_SEQ  , 'Some Val');
END;
```

Comment: I need a java solution, from anonymous block I know how to do it.

Comment: @Kartic Can you call the anonymous block from Java instead of using individual SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the next value of the sequence and populate your tables with this value.

```
int seq_val = 0;
ResultSet rs = stmt.execute("SELECT ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
if ( rs.next() ) {
  seq_val = rs.getInt(1);
}

Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO Table1(SeqId, OtherField1)" + "VALUES ("+seq_val+",'some_val')");

statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO Table2(ID,SeqId, OtherField1) " + "VALUES ('some_id',"+seq_val+",'some val')");

statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO Table3(ID,SeqId, OtherField1) " + "VALUES ('some_id',"+seq_val+",'some val')");

statement.executeBatch();
```

//pardon any mistakes in syntax as I didn't use any code editor to validate.
cheers

Comment: I thought of this, but this is not very improved version than our current implementation as for each iteration we have to fire a select statement. Can someone validate if this is the only way.

Comment: can u share the foreach statement you talked about, maybe that would give me some insights

Comment: Loop is for getting OtherField value. No other logic. I don't know, but if there is any way to group multiple statement and execute as single unit, that will do. Not sure if that is feasible at all.

Comment: @Kartic have u decided what answer works for you?, or did u use a different approach, do let us know.

Comment: I'll stick to current implementation as I got a feeling there is no real solution to my actual problem.